# What is the E[X| X, Y] when X and Y are dependent?

Tags: probability, expected-value

What is the $E[X| X, Y]$ when $X$ and $Y$ are dependent? Is it simply $X$?

I was expecting this result because the knowledge about $X$ is already known (as we are conditioning on $X$ and $Y$).

\begin{align*}
E[X| X, Y] = E[X|X] = X
\end{align*}

I don't have much knowledge in measure-theory to prove it is indeed the case. Can anyone explain it with a bit more detail?

Comment: You will get better answers if you explain what definition you are taking for $\mathbf{E}[X|X,Y]$. Using the measure-theoretic definition, this is obvious simply because $\sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(X,Y)$ and $\int_A X \;d\mathbf{P} = \int_A X\;d\mathbf{P}$.

Comment: I was looking at it from the analytical definition. What is your last equality means (LHS and RHS) are equivalent.

Comment: Exactly they're equivalent so $\mathbf{E}[X|X,Y] = X$. But that only makes sense if you know about Radon-Nikodym derivatives. What does "analytical definition" mean?

Comment: I tried to use the definition of $E[X|Y] = \int x f(x|y) dx$. But if I apply it in here $E[X|X, Y] = \int x f(x|x, y) dx$. But I am not sure how to look at the solution from this expression.

Comment: The formula $E[X|Y = y] = \int x f(x|y) dx$ works when you have a single random variable. But $X, Y$ is not a random variable so you cannot define the conditional expectation with respect to $X, Y$ in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you please explain to me what you have done in the last equality of your first comment. I get that $\sigma(x) \subset \sigma(X, Y)$. what it implies after that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra

Comment: @TrevorGunn I had a look at the wikipedia page. But I am not sure how to relate it with the last equality. If you can elaborate more as a post that will be useful.

Comment: Edit your question to add context to it. What is your background. What definitions do you know. What does $\mathbf{E}[X|X,Y]$ mean to you. Have you seen conditional expectation with respect to anything that isn't a random variable or a single event? People can give you an answer using measure theory and Radon-Nikodym derivatives but I don't see how that will be at all useful to you. And I simply don't have time to go back and forth in the comments about what you're *really* asking and what your questions should be.

Answer (score 3):

$E[X|\sigma(X,Y)]=X$ because of the "pulling out know factor" property of the conditional expectation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties).

Indeed, $X$ is $\sigma(X,Y)$-measurable because $\sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(X,Y)$, so you can take it out of the conditional expection. What is left is $XE[1|\sigma(X,Y)]=X$. Dependence between $X$ and $Y$ does not play any role here.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.